# Pandas - Generate multiple rows and multiple columns from pandas DataFrame where column is lists

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this dataframe that's formatted messily. The columns are `messages` and `url`, `url` is the URL to download the audio file associated with the row and `messages` is the conversation transcribed between 2 people. So for example:

```
[{'role': 'A',
   'message': 'Hello? Who is this?'},
  {'role': 'B'
   'message': "Hey, Belinda. This is Kurt Lou. Hope I'm honored to trouble for calling you today."},
  {'role': 'A',
   'message': "Alright, Curt. You've got me on the line now. What is this about?"}]
```

this is an example of a single row of `messages` column. So a row in the table could look like

```
messages | url
<list from above> | <some url>
```

I'm trying to create a new DataFrame where each row has `message`, `prev_message` and `url` the above example would generate the follow rows and columns.

```
message | prev_message | url
Hello? Who is this? | <None cause no prev message> | <url from `url` column>
Hey, Belinda. This is Kurt Lou. Hope I'm honored to trouble for calling you today. | Hello? Who is this? | <url from `url` column>
Alright, Curt. You've got me on the line now. What is this about? | Hey, Belinda. This is Kurt Lou. Hope I'm honored to trouble for calling you today. | <url from `url` column>
```

So each row is the message, the message that comes before it and the URL to the audio file associated with this conversation. I have this current code to do this:

```
import ast

def process_data_w_audio(df: pd.DataFrame):
    msg_list = list()
    bot_list = list()
    audio_fps = list()

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        messages_list = ast.literal_eval(row["messages"]) # cause list is string when reading from CSV
        url = row["url"]

        for i, msg_dict in enumerate(messages_list):
            msg_list.append(msg_dict["message"].strip())
            if i > 0:
                bot_list.append(messages_list[i - 1]["message"].strip())
            audio_fps.append(url)
                
    
    
    return pd.DataFrame({"message": msg_list, "prev_message": bot_list, "audio_fp": audio_fps})
```

The issue with this is that it's painfully slow it could take 5 hours just to go over 20k rows. How can I do this way faster?

Comment: Well, instead of appending to bot_list, since that column is just going to have the same values shifted, you could make the previous message column from the message column.

Comment: This is almost *gibberish*. The column names in the code don't match with those in the expected output. Also, you mention a `literal_eval` of *list-like* strings in the CSV (*hence, in the dataframe too*) but you provided a list of dictionaries as an input. It's very confusing and doesn't quite make sense. You should read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

1. Apply [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to column 'messages', explode the `df` ([`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)), and access the value for `key` 'message' via [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html).
2. On account of `explode`, the index can now be used to identify the groups: apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and return the shifted version of 'messages' per group ([`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)) and assign to new column 'prev_message'.
3. Some cosmetic changes at the end: rename 'messages' with [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get the desired order.

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df['messages'] = df['messages'].apply(literal_eval)
df = df.explode('messages')
df['messages'] = df['messages'].str['message']

df['prev_message'] = df.groupby(level=0)['messages'].shift()

df = (
    df.rename(columns={'messages': 'message'})
    .loc[:, ['message', 'prev_message', 'url']]
)

df

                                             message  \
0                                Hello? Who is this?   
0  Hey, Belinda. This is Kurt Lou. Hope I'm honor...   
0  Alright, Curt. You've got me on the line now. ...   
1                                Hello? Who is this?   
1  Hey, Belinda. This is Kurt Lou. Hope I'm honor...   
1  Alright, Curt. You've got me on the line now. ...   

                                        prev_message            url  
0                                                NaN  www.hello.com  
0                                Hello? Who is this?  www.hello.com  
0  Hey, Belinda. This is Kurt Lou. Hope I'm honor...  www.hello.com  
1                                                NaN  www.world.com  
1                                Hello? Who is this?  www.world.com  
1  Hey, Belinda. This is Kurt Lou. Hope I'm honor...  www.world.com
```

**Data sample**

```py
message = """[{'role': 'A', 'message': 'Hello? Who is this?'},{'role': 'B', 'message': "Hey, Belinda. This is Kurt Lou. Hope I'm honored to trouble for calling you today."},{'role': 'A', 'message': "Alright, Curt. You've got me on the line now. What is this about?"}]"""

data = {
    'messages': [message]*2,
    'url': ['www.hello.com', 'www.world.com']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

                                            messages            url
0  [{'role': 'A', 'message': 'Hello? Who is this?...  www.hello.com
1  [{'role': 'A', 'message': 'Hello? Who is this?...  www.world.com
```